Нужна ли запятая в указанном месте?
Практику он проходил на заводе, зарплата была хорошая (?) и коллектив его полюбил.

Нужна. ССП.
У нас три основы: он проходил практику; зарплата была хорошая; коллектив полюбил.
Практику он проходил на заводе, зарплата была хорошая, и коллектив его полюбил.

Скажите, пожалуйста, а если после этих основ будет продолжение, нужны ли будут эти же запятые? Например:
Практику он проходил на заводе, зарплата была хорошая (?) и коллектив его полюбил, поэтому устроился сюда с удовольствием.

Да, все запятые нужны.
